# Task with duration and no hours

Tags: ms-project, resources

I am trying to add a task to my project. The task is assigned to my customer. I want to give them 30 days to complete the task and I don't care how many hours it takes them. Other than the 30 day duration, the hours do not affect my project. How do I do this? I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Are you trying to figure out how to use some tool? Jira? MS Project? Your question is too unclear to be answerable as it is. Please clarify.

Comment: Welcome to PMSE. Please add some additional context, including what you've tried and why that's not working for you, or your question may be put on hold until it's revised.

Comment: Why does it matter if hours are loaded?  It might be a metric your customer would be interested in.  Also, if you do not want their costs to affect your budget, load those resources with a $0.00 cost rate in the resource table.  Hours in the schedule will not affect your ability to measure performance against your baseline.

Comment: It is throwing off my tracking to internal budget hours I am trying to stick to.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using MS Project. These are some ways to do what you want.

- Create a 30-day task but do not assign any resource. The task will be
  displayed and treated like any other task but since it has no
  resources assigned, it will have zero work hours.
- If you need to assign a resource (for reporting / filtering purposes), then you can
  use a material or cost resource. Neither of those resource types
  require work hours. I’d prefer to use a cost resource, because that way I could
  define the task’s related cost.
- Since it is a task that will be    carried on by your customer, then
  maybe you do not need to monitor    the task progress. In this case,
  you can use a simple milestone to    indicate the task’s finish date.

Note that the first two options use a 30-day task with no work, while the third option uses a milestone with no work and no duration. This means that in the first two options, the task will have certain weight for the percent complete calculation (“% complete” MS Project field) while the third option will not.

None of these options will have influence over “% work complete”, though.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am going to try to create the first two options. I am thinking that the 2nd one may just be what I want.